# Unable to use os.Mkdir() on Mac OS

Tags: macos, go

I'd like to start off by saying this was working yesterday and to the best of my knowledge my computer has not performed any updates in the last 48 hours.

The program I am writing executes this code:

```
createDatabasesFolderError := os.MkdirAll("./.minutesdb/databases", os.ModePerm)
checkErr(createDatabasesFolderError)
```

Which results in this error when running `go run .`:

```
2020/10/28 08:04:58 Error: mkdir /.minutesdb: read-only file system
exit status 1
```

Running `pwd` results in this:
`/Users/garrettlove/development/goworkspace/src/github.com/garrettlove8/minutesDB`

I thought this was an OS issue as opposed to a Go issue, however everything else on my computer works, including other coding stuff...

Comment: Maybe the src folder has a read-only permissions.

Comment: From a terminal, what does `mkdir -p "./.minutesdb/databases"` report?

Comment: @colm.anseo Running that command works

Answer (score 0):

You code's path - as quoted in the question - I suspect is a typo:

```
os.MkdirAll("./.minutesdb/databases")
```

as it does not match the logged error path `/.minutesdb` (missing the leading dot):

```
2020/10/28 08:04:58 Error: mkdir /.minutesdb read-only file system exit status 1
```

The error describes, understandably, a non-root user cannot write to the root `/` of the filesystem.

Add the missing leading dot to fix the path issue.